# Sort the state (array of objects) by date in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say you are given an array of objects in your React state, like this:

```
[
    {
      "id": "…",
      "title": "Brief history of Space Shuttle program",
      "date": "2016-10-29 19:00:00+01:00",
      "venue": "NASA History Museum"
    },
    {
      "id": "…",
      "title": "Why did the Challenger explode?",
      "date": "2016-11-31 18:30:00+01:00",
      "venue": "Albert II Library Building"
    }
  ]
```

Now you want to sort this by date, let's say you have a forum or something similar, where the first post should be the newest according to date.

How would you sort it? This was my attempt:

```
function sortExample (dataToSort) {
        let test = [...dataToSort];
        test.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)
    }
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work out quite well.  And most importantly, where would you place this function? I put it in my `useEffect`, that didn't seem to work for me either.

Comment: Hey there! Would you be able to share the rest of your code? Specifically, the useEffect code and the code related to fetching the data?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Sort it before you setState, this is recommended if you only need the data in this order everywhere.
2. Sort it where you use the data but keep the original data as is in the state.

Say we have:

```js
const [dataInState, setDataInState] = useState([]);
```

First one:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/data")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => setDataInState(json.sort(myCompareFunc))
}, [])
```

Second one:

Set state as usual, then in component body, before return:

```js
const sortedData = [...dataInState].sort(myCompareFunc)
```

Now you can use `sortedData` in JSX or elsewhere.

I recommend the first one due to performance reasons.